# asyncio.wait_for_completion() on dynamic list of tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp, python-3.8

I am writing a simple client to interact with a possibly overloaded and unreliable webserver. I assume that for any individual request, the server may never respond (request will timeout), or may respond with an error after a lengthy delay.

Because of this, for each "request" I want to issue repeated requests according to the following logic:

- Repeat the request (issue a new request) every second until one of the issued requests receives the expected response
- New requests should be issued concurrently with existing requests - existing requests should stay open until they receive a response or time out.
- Once the expected response is received, cancel (close) any requests that are still pending/open.

I can accomplish something close to this if I issue a fixed number of requests simultaneously at the beginning, then use `asyncio.as_completed()` to handle the requests as they finish and cancel any remaining pending requests:

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import random
import time
from sys import stdout


class FailedRequest(Exception):
    pass

async def get():
    '''A simple mock async GET request that returns a randomized status after a randomized delay'''
    await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0,10))
    return random.choices([200, 500], [0.2, 0.8])[0]

async def fetch(id):
    '''Makes a request using get(), checks response, and handles cancellation'''
    logging.info(f"Sending request {id}.")
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    try:
        response = await get()
        elapsed_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
            
        if response != 200:
            logging.error(f"Request {id} failed after {elapsed_time:.2f}s: {response}")
            raise FailedRequest()
        else:
            logging.info(f"Request {id} succeeded ({response}) after {elapsed_time:.2f}s!")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        logging.info(f"Cancelled request {id} after {time.perf_counter() - start_time:.2f}s.")
        raise

async def main():
    # Create 10 unique Tasks that wrap the fetch() coroutine
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(fetch(i)) for i in range(10)]

    # Iterate through the tasks as they are completed
    for coro in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        try:
            # Wait for the next task to finish. If the request errored out,
            # this line will raise a FailedRequest exception (caught below)
            await coro

            # If we get here, then a request succeeded. Cancel all of the tasks we started.
            for t in tasks:
                t.cancel()

        except (FailedRequest, asyncio.CancelledError) as e:
            pass

    logging.info("Finished!")
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(stream=stdout, level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    random.seed(3)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
2020-09-22 18:07:35,634:INFO: Sending request 0.
2020-09-22 18:07:35,635:INFO: Sending request 1.
2020-09-22 18:07:35,635:INFO: Sending request 2.
2020-09-22 18:07:35,635:INFO: Sending request 3.
2020-09-22 18:07:35,636:INFO: Sending request 4.
2020-09-22 18:07:35,636:INFO: Sending request 5.
2020-09-22 18:07:35,636:INFO: Sending request 6.
2020-09-22 18:07:35,636:INFO: Sending request 7.
2020-09-22 18:07:35,636:INFO: Sending request 8.
2020-09-22 18:07:35,637:INFO: Sending request 9.
2020-09-22 18:07:35,786:ERROR: Request 6 failed after 0.15s: 500
2020-09-22 18:07:36,301:ERROR: Request 5 failed after 0.66s: 500
2020-09-22 18:07:37,993:ERROR: Request 9 failed after 2.35s: 500
2020-09-22 18:07:38,023:ERROR: Request 0 failed after 2.39s: 500
2020-09-22 18:07:38,236:ERROR: Request 8 failed after 2.60s: 500
2020-09-22 18:07:39,351:INFO: Request 2 succeeded (200) after 3.72s!
2020-09-22 18:07:39,351:INFO: Cancelled request 1 after 3.72s.
2020-09-22 18:07:39,351:INFO: Cancelled request 3 after 3.72s.
2020-09-22 18:07:39,352:INFO: Cancelled request 4 after 3.72s.
2020-09-22 18:07:39,352:INFO: Cancelled request 7 after 3.72s.
2020-09-22 18:07:39,352:INFO: Finished!
```

However, I am struggling to understand a clean way to start by issuing a single request, then issue additional requests every second until one of the requests is successful, while still keeping track of all unfinished requests and cancelling any that are still pending.

This is as close as I've gotten:

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import random
import time
from sys import stdout


class FailedRequest(Exception):
    pass

async def get():
    '''A simple mock async GET request that returns a randomized status after a randomized delay'''
    await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0,10))
    return random.choices([200, 500], [0.2, 0.8])[0]

async def fetch(id):
    '''Makes a request using get(), checks response, and handles cancellation'''
    logging.info(f"Sending request {id}.")
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    try:
        response = await get()
        elapsed_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
            
        if response != 200:
            logging.error(f"Request {id} failed after {elapsed_time:.2f}s: {response}")
            raise FailedRequest()
        else:
            logging.info(f"Request {id} succeeded ({response}) after {elapsed_time:.2f}s!")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        logging.info(f"Cancelled request {id} after {time.perf_counter() - start_time:.2f}s.")
        raise

async def issue_requests(finished, requests):
    i = 0
    while not finished.is_set():
        requests.add(asyncio.create_task(fetch(i)))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        i += 1

async def handle_requests(finished, requests):
    # Iterate through the requests as they are completed
    for coro in asyncio.as_completed(requests):
        try:
            # Wait for the next task to finish. If the request errored out,
            # this line will raise a FailedRequest exception (caught below)
            await coro

            # If we get here, then a request succeeded. Cancel all of the tasks we started.
            finished.set()
            for r in requests:
                r.cancel()

        except (FailedRequest, asyncio.CancelledError):
            pass


async def main():
    finished = asyncio.Event()
    requests = set()

    await asyncio.gather(issue_requests(finished, requests), handle_requests(finished, requests))
    logging.info("Finished!")
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(stream=stdout, level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    random.seed(3)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

However, although the requests are launched as expected, the process does not stop when the first successful request returns:

```
2020-09-22 18:03:38,256:INFO: Sending request 0.
2020-09-22 18:03:39,264:INFO: Sending request 1.
2020-09-22 18:03:40,265:INFO: Sending request 2.
2020-09-22 18:03:40,643:ERROR: Request 0 failed after 2.39s: 500
2020-09-22 18:03:41,281:INFO: Sending request 3.
2020-09-22 18:03:42,281:INFO: Sending request 4.
2020-09-22 18:03:42,948:INFO: Request 4 succeeded (200) after 0.67s!
# requests 1, 2, and 3 should be cancelled here and the script should finish
2020-09-22 18:03:43,279:INFO: Sending request 5.
2020-09-22 18:03:43,976:ERROR: Request 2 failed after 3.71s: 500
2020-09-22 18:03:44,281:INFO: Sending request 6.
2020-09-22 18:03:44,718:ERROR: Request 1 failed after 5.45s: 500
2020-09-22 18:03:45,295:INFO: Sending request 7.
2020-09-22 18:03:46,307:INFO: Sending request 8.
...
```

I think the issue is that when `asyncio.as_completed(requests)` is called in `handle_requests()`, `requests` is an empty set, so `as_completed()` returns an empty iterator and `handle_requests()` returns immediately.

It feels like it should be possible to do this with `asyncio` at a high level, but I am struggling to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this for example (using `while` loop):

```py
is_finished = False
tasks = []

def cancel_tasks():
  for t in tasks:
    t.cancel()

async def fetch(count):
  '''Makes a request using get(), checks response, and handles cancellation'''
  logging.info(f"Sending request {count}.")
  start_time = time.perf_counter()
  try:
    response = await get()
    elapsed_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time

    if response != 200:
      logging.error(f"Request {count} failed after {elapsed_time:.2f}s: {response}")
      raise FailedRequest()
    else:
      global is_finished
      is_finished = True
      logging.info(f"Request {count} succeeded ({response}) after {elapsed_time:.2f}s!")
      cancel_tasks()

  except asyncio.CancelledError:
    logging.info(f"Cancelled request {count} after {time.perf_counter() - start_time:.2f}s.")
    raise

async def main():
  count = 0
  while not is_finished:
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(fetch(count)))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    count += 1

  # Wait for all tasks to cancel:
  await asyncio.wait(tasks)

  logging.info("Finished!")
```

**EDIT:** slightly improved so that it cancels all the tasks ASAP and then waits for all of them to be canceled before logging 'Finished'

Comment: This works, although setting the finished flag and cancelling the other tasks inside of `fetch()` feels like a code smell to me. What if `fetch()` doesn't have visibility to the other tasks or `is_finished`?

Comment: The other downside to this approach is that the `tasks` list will include completed `Task` objects. If the requests consistently return error codes and `main()` has been running for a long time, the `tasks` list will grow very large, and iterating through it to cancel the small number of pending tasks may take a non-trivial amount of time. This approach needs a clean way to remove completed tasks from the list, so `cancel_tasks()` operates on only those tasks which are still pending.

Comment: I just showed you the way how to achieve what you want, it's up to you to make your code cleaner and more optimized. Instead of `tasks` array use a dictionary where you store a task by `count` key. This way you'll be able to remove it once it fails.
Another optimization would be to not start a new request if you have N amount of pending tasks.

Instead of defining logic for finishing in fetch() method just call `handle_finished` method when succeeded and in that method cancel all tasks and set `is_finished` flag to `True`

Comment: Agreed, it's a valid solution, although I was hoping this question could turn into a discussion on writing idiomatic async Python. What I'm really looking for is a solution that assumes `fetch()` is an arbitrary function and doesn't require it to call a specific function to handle cancelling the other tasks, since e.g. `fetch()` may be provided by a 3rd party module. The solution you presented still feels inelegant to me, as if there has to be a better way to do it using the high-level `asyncio` primitives, but I appreciate your contribution.

Comment: Not sure how you could assume that `fetch()` is an arbitrary function. You have to write your own custom abstraction to achieve what you want. In you example I think it's `get()` method that can be considered an arbitrary function that makes HTTP request.
Perhaps what really bothers you is the naming of methods?
I'd probably wrap this whole code into a single function called `fetch_persistently(url)` or smth like that (pretty much your current `main()`), renamed your `fetch()` to `fetch_attempt()`. So that for each `fetch_persistently` call there is a separate scoped `tasks` variable created

Comment: This solution will always wait for at least a second, even if the first task finishes immediately.

Comment: Can transform sleep into a task and cancel it as well on success

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are deceptively simple at first, but actually require some thought. If I understood them correctly, you want something like this:

```
async def _spawner(async_fn, done):
    # spawn a new task every second, notifying the caller when
    # any task completes
    running = set()
    def when_done(task):
        running.remove(task)
        done.put_nowait(task)

    while True:
        new_task = asyncio.create_task(async_fn())
        new_task.add_done_callback(when_done)
        running.add(new_task)
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            # we're canceled, cancel the tasks that are still running
            for t in running:
                t.cancel()
            raise

async def try_until_successful(async_fn):
    done = asyncio.Queue()
    # run the spawner in the background so it can run
    # independently of us
    spawner_task = asyncio.create_task(_spawner(async_fn, done))

    # collect completed tasks until the one we're happy with
    while True:
        task = await done.get()
        if task.exception() is None:
            # task didn't raise - we got our result!
            spawner_task.cancel()
            return task.result()
```

Those functions don't assume anything about the coroutine passed as `async_fn`. You can use `lambda` or `functools.partial` to create any kind of callable, as long as it ends up returning a coroutine object (the object returned by just calling an `async def` and what you normally pass to `await`). Also, they don't use global flags, so you could await several instances of `try_until_successful` in parallel.

To invoke `fetch()` with monotonically increasing IDs you could call it like this:

```
async def main():
    cnt = 0
    async def fetch_incrementing():
        nonlocal cnt
        cnt += 1
        await fetch(cnt)
    await try_until_successful(fetch_incrementing)
```

Comment: Do you think it's worth storing an extra flag in your `while` loop where you use `sleep(1)`?
I mean so that it is `while not is_done:` and not `while True:`. I believe you assume that as soon as `done.put_nowait(task)` is called we synchronously go to our loop where we called `task = await done.get()`. But is this assumption correct? I think `await done.get()` will return a value asynchronously so there is a chance (perhaps super small) that `sleep(1)` will be finished before that and it will create an extra fetch task. Thoughts?

Comment: @GProst That's a very interesting question. When `when_done` fires, `_spawner` is awaiting `sleep()` and `try_until_successful` is awaiting `queue.get()`, those being the only `await` in the respective coroutines. `put_nowait` will make the `queue.get()` wake up, but that will happen in the next event loop iteration, let's call it iteration 1. As you correctly point  out, it is possible (if unlikely) for `sleep(1)` to elapse at iteration 1, in which case both `_spawner` and `try_until_successful` are eligible to resume in that iteration, and it is unspecified which one it will be.

Comment: So it's possible for a extra `fetch` to be scheduled - but it won't start executing until the iteration after that, iteration 2. (That's how most of asyncio works.) And in iteration 1 the resumption of `try_until_successful` is still pending, which will cancel the spawner. Spawner's cancellation will be processed in iteration 2, the same iteration when the new `fetch` is also starting. Spawner reacts to cancellation by cancelling all running tasks (including the unnecessary new `fetch`), but this cancellation will only be processed in iteration 3.

Comment: So yes, an extra `fetch()` will start running and have time to e.g. open a network request before it's cancelled, good catch! But I'm not sure adding the condition is worth complicating the code. Currently there is a separation of concerns between `_spawner` (which spawns new tasks until cancelled) and `try_until_successful` (which decides what it means to be "successful"). We could of course transfer a boxed boolean which try_... could use to tell spawner to exit, but it seems like too much complication for an edge case of a system that is designed to run on a best-effort basis.

Comment: If this edge case is ever an issue for the OP, I'd leave adding the flag as an exercise for the reader.